# Can I send a notification with their corresponding location to a person using twilio?

Tags: twilio

I am working in a project that uses twilio API but i dont know if this is applicable. my concern is I want my friend a notification that also indicates my exact location.

example, if I press help button, the app will immediately send a notification to a specific person.

hope you can help me.

Comment: Which channel? Can you provide much more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Twilio provides many ways to do this. The implementation depends on the details of your app, but architecturally you will probably end up implementing:

1. A native/web application with a help button. When the help button is pressed, it will get the GPS location of the device and make a call to a Twilio endpoint.
2. A cloud-hosted Twilio service that exposes an endpoint that your button calls, such as [Twilio Functions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions). [Here is how you'll send a text message to your administrator from that function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/quickstart/programmable-sms-functions).
3. You can read the GPS coordinates passed in by your app and include them in the text message. [Here is a blog post I wrote using Twilio Functions and text input](https://www.twilio.com/blog/what-framework-are-you-watson-autopilot).

Please provide more information about the platform you're using for your app and what kind of notification you want your administrator to receive and I can give more detailed advice!